# Is it possible to make *ngIf DOM insertion less choppy?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I have the HTML structure similar to this:

```
<div class="item">...innerHTML...</div>

<div *ngIf="condition" @OnConditionTrueSlidngAnimation>This is the div I have a problem with.</div>

<div class="item">...innerHTML...</div>
```

As you may have guessed when the **condition** is `true` and the `div` appears in a DOM the animation is triggered. This animation slides the `div` `height` from 0 to *amount*. My problem is that whenever this `div` is inserted into DOM the `div` below is forcefully pulled down by some distance so the element above can fit between this two and play its animation. This whole pulling process is visibly coppy/laggy reducing UX. Is it possible to somehow prevent this behaviour or to create some space between them initially? Hope I got my point clear, if not I will supply more code samples.

Comment: Space is easy, just wrap it all in a div with a specified height and it will reserve that vertical space even when it's empty.